# Error: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing

please help me cant do this thing to work to me sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

```
 if (shape.hasImage())
                    {
                        // If this shape is an image, extract image to file
                        String extension = ImageTypeToExtension(shape.getImageData().getImageType());
                        String imageFileName = MessageFormat.format("Image.ExportImages.{0} Out.{1}", imageIndex, extension);
                        String strBarCodeImageExtracted = "" + imageFileName;
                        shape.getImageData().save(strBarCodeImageExtracted);

                        // Recognize barcode from this image
                        BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader ((BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(strBarCodeImageExtracted),BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard);
                        while (reader.read())
                        {
                            System.out.println("codetext: " + reader.getCodeText());
                        }
                        imageIndex++;
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`ImageIO#read(URL u)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) instead of `Toolkit#getImage`?

Comment: Please share some more code to analysis it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was accepted after the comment was written, so one has to assume that the comment was the actual solution. The comment was

> ... to replace `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(...)` with `ImageIO.read(...)` ...

---

*Original answer:*

You may either try to read the image direcly with `ImageIO`, or consider painting the image into a newly allocated BufferedImage, e.g. with a method like

```
public static BufferedImage convertToBufferedImage(Image image)
{
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
        image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

And then in your case:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(strBarCodeImageExtracted);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = convertToBufferedImage(image);
BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader(bufferedImage,BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard);
```

Comment: im getting this " Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0 "

Comment: OK, you could now try to mess around with a MediaTracker, but probably the simplest solution would be to replace `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(...)` with `ImageIO.read(...)` as long as there is no profound reason to *not* do this.