# Save java.awt.Image to disk in java

Tags: java

I have read clob from oracle procedure and convert them into java.awt.Image object by the following code .

```
InputStream stream = clob.getAsciiStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int a1 = stream.read();
                while (a1 >= 0) {
                  output.write((char) a1);
                  a1 = stream.read();
                }
                Image myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(output.toByteArray());
                output.close();
```

Now, I want to save myImage to hard disk. So, What must I do to save these java.awt.Image to file ?

### My try :

I have cast the myImage to BufferedImage and then write this to ImageIo by the following code :

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage)myImage;
               ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg",new File("E:\\out.jpg"));
```

But I am getting the following exception :

```
Got Exception as : sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at com.connect.home.Home.getHomeParameter(Home.java:103)
    at com.connect.home.Home.main(Home.java:141)
```

How can I remove this error ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426040/error-sun-awt-image-toolkitimage-cannot-be-cast-to-java-awt-image-bufferedimage

Comment: Got Exception as : Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0

Comment: Use the ImageIO.write method.

Comment: where should I use ImageIO.write method ?

Comment: The linked answer already tells you how to use `ImageIO.read` (not `#write`).

Comment: `myImage` always remains `ToolkitImage` at runtime, no matter if you cast it to `Image` or `BufferedImage `. 

It’s always possible to cast sub-class to a super-class (`TookitImage` to `Image`) However its not (always) possible to cast it to some other class (`BufferedImage`), even if it shares the same super class.

Comment: @AlexanderOrlov *"However its not (always) possible to cast it to some other class"* You don't need that "always" here, because you can never do such cast. Only cast to the same class or a parent class. `TookitImage` and `BufferedImage` are brothers (same parent class), and this cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

First

> Oracle JDBC drivers support the manipulation of data streams in either
>   direction between server and client. The drivers support all stream
>   conversions: binary, ASCII, and Unicode. Following is a brief
>   description of each type of stream:
>
> Binary. Used for RAW bytes of data, and corresponds to the getBinaryStream method
>
> ASCII. Used for ASCII bytes in ISO-Latin-1 encoding, and corresponds to the getAsciiStream method
>
> Unicode. Used for Unicode bytes with the UTF-16 encoding, and corresponds to the getUnicodeStream method

So probably you will need to use `clob.getBinaryStream` to retrieve your stream.

Second. You can not save `ToolKitImage` whith [ImageIO::write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) because it expect a `RenderedImage`  instance.And `ToolkitImage` not implements this interface.

So you have two options.

Read the stream with `ImageIO`

```
    RenderedImage image = ImageIO.read(clob.getBinaryStream());
    ImageIO.write(image, "JPG",new File("E:\\out.jpg"));
```

Or draw the `ToolkitImage` on a `RenderedImage`

```
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(myImage.getWidth(null), myImage.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bi.getGraphics().drawImage(myImage,0,0, null);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", new File("E:\\out.jpg"));
```